# Center text next to floated image

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I have an image with three lines of text to the right.  The text is centering on the remaining space on the line, but I would like to center it on the page so that all of the text is centered (the text below the image looks good).  Is this possible?

```
<div style="position:relative">
<img src="RGB2748.jpg" style="float:left;" width="70" />
</div>

<div style=" height:10px; font-size:22px; text-align:center;">Text</div>
<div style="height:10px; font-size:20px; text-align:center;">Text</div> 
<div style="height:10px; font-size:16px; text-align:center;">Text</div>
...
...
More text
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you floating the IMG tag if you don't want the text to wrap around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean by 'center'? vertically? so use e.g. 'line-height:100px' and 'vertical-align: middle'.

the position:relative doesn't make sense in this context. use float:left to position e.g. two divs side by side (beginning on the left side) and clear:both (as said), to continue positioning divs under these two.

edit:

**one solution:**

```
<div style="height:50px; font-size:22px; text-align:center; position:relative; width: 100%;">
    <img src="RGB2748.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 70px" />
    Text
</div>
<div style="height:50px; font-size:20px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div> 
<div style="height:50px; font-size:16px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div>
```

*pro*: text is centered to page

*contra*: if text is too wide it would be hidden in parts under the img

**modified first solution (if you better like it this way):**

```
<div style="height:50px; font-size:22px; text-align:center; position:relative; width: 100%;">
    <img src="RGB2748.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width: 70px" />
    <div style="height:50px; font-size:22px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div>
    <div style="height:50px; font-size:20px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div> 
    <div style="height:50px; font-size:16px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div>
</div>
```

**another solution:**

```
<div style="background: lightblue; width: 10%; float:left;">
    <img src="RGB2748.jpg" style="float: left; width: 70px;" />
</div>
<div style="background: lightgray; width: 90%; float:left;">
    <div style="line-height:50px; font-size:22px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div>
    <div style="line-height:100px; font-size:20px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div> 
    <div style="line-height:10px; font-size:16px; text-align:center; width: 100%;">Text</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">following text</div>
```

*pro*: text will be displayed not matter how long it is

*contra*: text isn't centered to the page, but only to the surrounding div

Comment: Sorry - I meant horizontally.  The text below the image is centered on the page, and I'd like the text that is directly to the right of the image to also be centered on the page (as if the image wasn't there)

Comment: the thing is: position the first div relative, so that you can position the img inside this div absolute (with top and left set to 0 to put it on the upper left corner). I added width, so that your divs are forced to be placed under each other. you could alternatively use clear:both for each div.

Comment: Sweet Moses, that did it.  Thank you sasha! (thank you for the explanation as well)

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` to the style of the first text block/div.

Comment: Thank you- that does center it, but it shifts the text below the image - I do want it to the right of the image, just centered on the page.

Comment: You will need to float the DIV surrounding the image, not the image itself. You will also need to give the DIV a fixed width.